# How to infer sum type of values picked from property from passed array of objects

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I am trying to pass array of objects to a function. This function has to look at all types of values behind one of the properties of its objects. These types of values should be passed as type parameter to a returned function

What types have to be filled as question marks to achieve these results?

```js
type A = { key: 'a' };
type B = { key: 'b' };
type C = { key: 'c' };

type Xs = (A | B | C)[];

const fn1 = (arg1: ???) => {
  return {
    f2: (arg2: ???) => null,
  };
};

// should fail
fn1([]).f2('a');
// should also fail
fn1([{ key: 'a' }]).f2('c');
// correct
fn1([{ key: 'a' }, { key: 'b' }]).f2('a');
```

Something like `Pick<ValuesType<(A | B | C)[]>, 'key'>['key']` could be used to get `"a" | "b" | "c"` type. But how to infer the subset of types forming the passed array remains puzzle to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const fn1 = <K extends string>(arg1: {key: K}[]) => {
  return {
    f2: (arg2: K) => null,
  };
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmAjDAvDAPAaRgUwB5Q5gAmEM0ATgJZgDmAfABQCGFtiAXDAN4DWOATy6YAvgG0AugEpU9HgFgAUDBgUcUAK4UwC5SvgAmLizZGYmGSjlgNAG1sAaJSpEBuJW6VKA9N-IALEDtieGYqWyUEREZJKQA6OANGAHJmZKl3RV8AoNsQ5lsIEFDwyKQY7hh+IRhU5JgRaQSk5OB0zOzQCjVgKDLosUrqrjqGhx4qwRGAI3rG+MSUtIylIA)

If you must restrict the original argument to only be of type `Xs` or a subtype, then try this:

```
const fn1 = <T extends Xs>(arg1: T) => {
  return {
    f2: (arg2: T[number]['key']) => null,
  };
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUDWEQC4oHICGOUAvgNwCwAUKJFAEILJobY4BGhpl10Awgyuiy4Axh3IUu4aAA0AzgwAUcAD50oqngEoA2gF1xlYQHsAdrOBQAZiYCMDADwAVKBAAewCCYAm8uQD4FPAAnAHMbbEdNBD9kSigoIIhgAFcgk1iKePjLACZsQNC8qEdtE2SAW1YIIN1tHEEcXSj4GLKAGzaAGjjicU4JCgB6QahZAAsjZLavKzwASzbKaxsFPU0AOlyFfBxNcWHRiamZvDbZI1mFpdtVgWZcAmImzZzt0T3KA+MgxOFga5W2juQh2xE6jEELHYTw2Wx2HwoQA)